# Pandas df.to_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am trying to create a table via python dataframe in airflow dag. I already extracted data from a big query table and loaded into pandas dataframe. How can I create a table in MySQL?

```
def bq_extraction():
    
    source_table = 'analytics.buyer_data' -- Bigquery table
    destination_table = 'marketing.buyer_data' -- Mysql Table

    sql_query = f"""SELECT  email,
                            count_products
                    FROM {source_table}
                """

    df = bq_client.query(query=sql_query, job_config=bq_query_config).to_dataframe()
    df.columns = ['email', 'count_wishlist_products']
    print(df.shape) -- This is working fine
```

I tried to add a mysql hook using below code

```
hook = MySqlHook('connection_id')
engine = hook.get_sqlalchemy_engine()

df.to_sql('marketing.buyers_data', con=engine)
```

Error;

```
ERROR - to_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'
```

Comment: [df.to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen: I tried this, but getting below error,
ERROR - to_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'

Comment: I already added con. could you please help here